# Gremlin group by on multiple properties

Tags: elasticsearch, graph-databases, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm able to write aggregation/group by query on single property of an vertex.
The below query includes ACL valuation while retrieving data which you can ignore while answering the question.

```
 g.V().has('user','userId',123).emit().until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).repeat(out('member_of')).outE('has_permission').has('permission','view').inV().as('f').select('f').group().by('folderType').by(count())
```

This gives me the following results

```
==>[PROJECT:2,RegularFolder:4,ORGANISATION:7,DIVISION:4]
```

just like folderType there are multiple properties for folder vertex.

the expectation is that like elasticsearch aggregation query results.

```
"folderType":[PROJECT:2,RegularFolder:4,ORGANISATION:7,DIVISION:4]
"CreatedBy":[user1:2,user2:4,user3:7,user4:4]
```

How to write the gremlin query which gives the above result and near to the expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said to ignore your initial query but I can't help but rewrite to:

```
g.V().has('user','userId',123).
  emit().
  until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
  repeat(out('member_of')).
  outE('has_permission').has('permission','view').inV().
  groupCount().
    by('folderType')
```

as the step label of "f" isn't needed and it's more precise to use `groupCount()` in this case. If you need to `groupCount()` on multiple properties I suppose there might be several ways but in this case as you describe it, I think that the easiest thing is to calculate two `groupCount()` side-effects and then `cap()` out both of them together:

```
g.V().has('user','userId',123).
  emit().
  until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
  repeat(out('member_of')).
  outE('has_permission').has('permission','view').inV().
  groupCount('folderType').
    by('folderType').
  groupCount('CreatedBy').
    by('CreatedBy').
  cap('folderType','CreatedBy')
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that works. and yes the select not required in my first that was part of my other use-cases i was trying out. thanks for correction.